# How do I process ActiveSupport::Notifications events?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, notifications

I've looked at the documentation for `ActiveSupport::Notifications` but I'm a little unclear about how to use it. Here's what I have right now:

```
class Foo
  ...

  def xyz
    # other stuff
    ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument(:interesting)
      expensive_operation(123, 'apple')    # We want to instrument this.
    end
  end
end
```

What I would like to do is have another class, `Auditor`, invoke `puts "event #{event}"` whenever the `interesting` event is raised. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

A good resources is from railscast.com

http://railscasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3

Another resource that you can take a look at is Jose Valim's book Crafting Rails Application.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few good resources to get you started:

- [Using ActiveSupport::Notifications and ActiveSupport::Concern To Create An Audit Trail](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/06/09/using-activesupportnotifications-and-activesupportconcern-to-create-an-audit-trail/)
- [Digging Deep with ActiveSupport::Notifications](https://github.com/newhavenrb/conferences/wiki/Digging-Deep-with-ActiveSupport%3a%3aNotifications)
- [ActiveSupport::Notifications API Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html)
- [Active Support Instrumentation Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html) - This contains a list of all available notifications that you can subscribe to.
- [RailsCasts #249 - Notifications in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3)